# Why android.support.v4 is added automatically?

Tags: android

I am new in Android. I have seen appcompat v7 is declared in the build.gradle but I can't seems to find supportv4 declare in the build.gradle and yet I still can find it inside exploded-aar folder inside build (gradle project).

[image: build.gradle]

Comment: appcompat-v7 is dependent on support-v4, so it is automatically included

Answer (score 2, accepted):

appcompat-v7 provides additional support for android.support.v7 which requires/includes android.support.v4. It is possible for any library to provide dependencies which you can reuse.